# Including GLIBC in a conda package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, glibc

I'm learning how to create conda packages, and I am having trouble with a package that will work locally, but that when downloaded from anaconda into a different server will return an error:

> /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found

The `meta.yaml` looks like the following:

```
package:
  name: app
  version: 2.4

source:
  git_url: https://gitlab.com/user/repo.git
  git_tag: v2.4

requirements:
  build:
  host:
  run:

about:
  home: https://gitlab.com/user/repo
  license: GPL-3
  license_family: GPL
  summary: blabla.
```

The app is build with a simple `build.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
echo $(pwd)
make

BIN=$PREFIX/bin
mkdir -p $BIN
cp app $BIN
```

I assumed that `build: glibc >= 2.29` under `requirements` would make the job, but that results in an error when running `conda build .`.

How can I include GLIBC in the package? is that something meant to be done *manually*? from the package version I can download from anaconda, I can see other packages are downloaded as well (e.g. `libgcc-ng`) that I did not really mention in the `meta.yaml` or anywhere.

Comment: I'm not clear on the details, but it seems GLIBC dependencies come from the build system. That is, the error indicates that the package was compiled on a system that was using a GLIBC v2.29, but that the system you try to run on is older. So, the resolution is either rebuild on an older image or update your deployment system. Alternatively, I think Conda Forge provides distributable sysroots, which you can build against (see [docs](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/infrastructure.html?highlight=glibc#centos-sysroot-for-linux-platforms)).

Comment: Also, maybe ensure that the build is linking to Conda-supplied libraries and not just system libs. The fact that you have no requirements listed in **meta.yaml** is rather strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I include GLIBC in the package?

You *can't*, for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

Your best bet is to build on a system (or in a docker container) which has the lowest version of GLIBC you need to support (i.e. the version installed on the server(s) you will be running your package on).

Comment: All right, that makes sense, thank you for the reply!